# How to make a perl one-liner "line-endings agnostic"

Tags: regex, perl, newline

I have scratched my head for one hour on a perl oneliner failing because the file had CRLF line endings. It has a regex with group match at the end of the line, and the CR got included in the match, making bad stuff with using the backreference for replace.

I ended up specifying the CRLF manually in the regex, but is there a way to get perl handle automatically line-ending *whatever they are*?

Original command is

```
perl -pe  's/foo bar(.*)$/foo $1 bar/g' file.txt
```

"Correct" command is

```
perl -pe  's/foo bar(.*)\r\n/foo $1 bar\r\n/g' file.txt
```

I know I can also convert line endings before processing, I'm interested in how to get Perl handle this case gracefully.

Example file (save with CRLF line endings!)

```
[19:06:57.033] foo barmy
[19:06:57.033] foo baryour
```

Expected output

```
[19:06:57.033] foo my bar
[19:06:57.033] foo your bar
```

Output with original command (bar goes at line beginning because it's matched together with carriage return):

```
bar:06:57.033] foo my
bar:06:57.033] foo your
```

Comment: what if you use \s* in this case. I always use this in another language.

Comment: [Read the documentation about modifiers](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) and use the `s` modifier `/gs` :)

Comment: @Darka: using `\s*` doesn't work, it still catches CR in the `.*`

Comment: @HamZa: using `/gs` modifier doesn't work

Comment: @CharlesB ok, I'm seeing a wild `$`, what's it doing there ? Also could you provide an example of input and expected output ?

Comment: @HamZa: the `$` is here to match the end of the line, I want to capture everything from `bar` to the end. Sure it's not needed, but removing it doesn't change anything

Comment: @CharlesB what about you use the `m` modifier ? [demo](http://regex101.com/r/wN6mO7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **`\R` escape sequence** <sup>Perl **v5.10+**; see `perldoc rebackslash` or the [documentation online](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html#Misc)</sup>, which matches "generic newlines" (platform-agnostically)  *can* be made to work here (example uses Bash to create the multi-line input string):

```
$ printf 'foo barmy\r\nfoo baryour\r\n' | perl -pe 's/foo bar(.*?)\R/foo $1 bar\n/gm'
foo my bar
foo your bar
```

Note that the only difference to [Ether's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19695574/45375) is **use of a *non-greedy* construct** (`.*?` rather than just `.*`), which makes all the difference here.

Read on, if you want to know more.

---

**Background:**

It is an example of a **pitfall associated with `\R`, which stems from the fact that it can match *one or two* characters** - either `\r\n` or, typically, `\n`:<sup>[1]</sup>

With the greedy `(.*)` construct , `"my\r"` - *including* the `\r` - is captured, because the regex engine apparently only backtracks by *one* character to look for `\R`, which the remaining `\n` *by itself* also satisfies.

By contrast, using the non-greedy `(.*?)` construct causes `\R` to match the `\r\n` *sequence*, as intended.

<sup>[1] **`\R` matches MORE than just `\r\n` and `\n`**: it matches any single character that is classified as **vertical whitespace** in Unicode terms, which also includes `\v` (vertical tab), `\f` (form feed), `\r` (by itself), and the following Unicode chars: `0x133 (NEXT LINE)`, `0x2028 (LINE SEPARATOR)`, `0x8232 (LINE SEPARATOR)` and `0x8233 (PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR)`</sup>

Answer (score 6):

First of all, let's keep in mind that

```
perl -ple's/foo bar(.*)\z/foo $1 bar/g' file.txt
```

is short for something close to

```
perl -e'
   while (<>) {
      chomp;
      s/foo bar(.*)\z/foo $1 bar/g;
      print $_, $/;
   }
' file.txt
```

---

Perl makes it so code can read/write local text files in a platform independent manner.

In a comment, you asked how to read/write both local text files and foreign text files in a platform independent manner.

First, you'll have to disable Perl's normal handling.

```
binmode STDIN;
binmode STDOUT;
```

Then you'll have to handle the multiple line endings.

```
sub mychomp { (@_ ? $_[0] : $_) =~ s/(\s*)\z//; $1 }

while (<STDIN>) {
   my $le = mychomp($_);
   s/foo bar(.*)\z/foo $1 bar/g;
   print($_, $le);
}
```

So instead of

```
perl -ple's/foo bar(.*)\z/foo $1 bar/g' file.txt
```

you would have

```
perl -e'
   sub mychomp { (@_ ? $_[0] : $_) =~ s/(\s*)\z//; $1 }

   binmode STDIN;
   binmode STDOUT;
   while (<STDIN>) {
      my $le = mychomp($_);
      s/foo bar(.*)\z/foo $1 bar/g;
      print($_, $le);
   }
' <file
```

Comment: Works on every file, thanks! not really a one-liner anymore, though

Comment: And it works on all systems (except ancient MacOS which isn't supported by Perl anyway). As for not being a one-liner, that's the cost of supporting 4 different combinations of systems and file types.

Answer (score 4):

In newer perls, you can use `\R` in your regex to strip off all end-of-line characters (it includes both `\n` and `\r`). See [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Comment: Seemed a good solution, it doesn't work. I tried `perl -pe  's/foo bar(.*)\R/foo $1 bar\n/gm' fix-cr.txt` and `perl -pe  's/foo bar(\N*)\R/foo $1 bar\n/gm' fix-cr.txt`, none of them work (get the same result as with a normal regex). What do I miss?

Comment: @CharlesB: It works if you use a non-greedy construct: replace `(.*)` with `(.*?)`; see my answer for background.

Answer (score 1):

You can say:

```
perl -pe 's/foo bar([^\015]*)(\015?\012)/foo $1 bar$2/g' *.txt
```

The line endings would be preserved, i.e. would be the same as the input file.

---

You might also want to refer to [`perldoc perlport`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#Newlines).

Comment: @CharlesB What's obfuscated about that?  Isn't `\015\012` CRLF?

Comment: @CharlesB `\015` == `\r`; `\012` == `\n`.

Comment: Sure, it's understandable (obfuscate isn't appropriate sorry). I mean makes the regex less readable, while I'm looking for something (option, modifier, don't know what) that keeps the regex "clean"

Comment: @CharlesB Sorry, I'm not aware of a *modifier* that'd help you achieve your _goal_.

Comment: @CharlesB BTW, have you seen [perldoc perlport](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#Newlines)?

Comment: @devnull: you can use `(\R)` in place of `(\015?\012)`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I guess that'd require 5.10

Comment: In the absence of >= 5.10.1 may I suggest:

  perl -pe '$lf = qr/([^\015]*)(\015?\012)/; s/foo bar$lf/foo $1 bar$2/g' *.txt

or something similar.  You're going to need weirdness.  Encapsulate it.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to get perl handle automatically platform-specific line-ending?

Yes. It's actually the default.

The issue is that you're trying to handle Windows line endings on a unix platform.

This will definitely do it:

```
perl -pe'
    BEGIN {
       binmode STDIN,  ":crlf";
       binmode STDOUT, ":crlf";
    }
    s/foo bar(.*)$/foo $1 bar/g;
' <file.txt
```

Might I suggest you keep doing it manually?

Alternatively, you could convert the file to a text file and convert it back.

```
<file.orig dos2unix | perl -pe'...' | unix2dos >file.new
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's still platform dependent. If I use this command on a LF file, it will output a CRLF file (or even fail to parse)

Comment: @CharlesB, That's not true. It handles Windows files in a platform independent manner like you asked. If you want to handle local files in a platform independent manner, use your original code.

Comment: It makes perfect sense, my goal is to handle CRLF and LF files in a platform independent manner

Comment: doesn't work either. Also, original code says `syntax error at -e line 3, near ",  :"
syntax error at -e line 4, near ", :"`

Comment: Low-tech answer: How about just making the endings optional with question marks: perl -pe  's/foo bar(.*)(\r?\n?)/foo $1 bar$2/g' file.txt

Comment: @Magnus, That won't handle LF files on Windows

Comment: `':crlf'` is causing the syntax error within the `perl -pe'...'`

Comment: ah, I thought you meant the code I had in the comment right before the one where you mentioned `:`, not the code in my answer. It's just a problem with escaping. Fixed.